# Trouble with loading new scene after a certain amount of time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load a new scene after clicking on the GUI.Button, and is working, but i want the level to load after a certain amount of time has passed, and my code is not working, what should i change or add to the script?

```
void OnGUI () {

    GUI.skin = zenzaiSkin;

    if(GUI.Button(new Rect((Screen.width/2-185),560,370,80), "START")) {
        loadLevel1 = true;
        audio.Play ();
    }




}

public IEnumerator loadLevel() {
        if(loadLevel1 = true){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(secondsWaiting);
            Application.LoadLevel(1);
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `if(loadLevel1 = true){` should be `if(loadLevel1 == true){`, notice the double equals sign

Answer (score 0):

well did you call the function ? i can't see the call... just add

```
StartCoroutine(loadLevel());
```

under audio.play 
so your code should look like something like this

```
void OnGUI () {

    GUI.skin = zenzaiSkin;

    if(GUI.Button(new Rect((Screen.width/2-185),560,370,80), "START")) {
        loadLevel1 = true;
        audio.Play ();
StartCoroutine(loadLevel());

  }





}
```